# Recognizing the sequence 1/16, 1/8, 3/16, 1/4, 5/16, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, pattern-recognition

> What is the missing number?
>   $$\frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{5}{16}, \ \ \  [?]$$

$$A. \frac{5}{4}\quad B. \frac{3}{4}\quad C. \frac{5}{8}\quad D. \frac{3}{8}$$

Spoiler: Answer is $D$, but I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: OMG, of course. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Am I the only one who thought $\frac{1}{2}$ before reading the possible options? :)

Comment: No, the next two numbers should definitely be 1/2 and 7/16 :-)

Comment: @Thomas I did consider it, but then thought it wasn't just right. First of all, I'd be generalizing from just two data points. Secondly I'd be ignoring the other three data points, which supposedly were there for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{8}=\frac{2}{16}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{16}, \frac{5}{16}$$

So the $i$th term is of the form $$\frac{i}{16}$$ Therefore, the next term is $$\frac{6}{16}=\frac{3}{8}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{5}{16}$$
The above is the same as $\displaystyle\frac1{16},\frac2{16},\frac3{16},\frac4{16},\frac5{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another sequence-recognizing technique
is to look at the difference between consecutive terms.

In this case,
$\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}
= \frac{1}{16}
$,
$\frac{3}{16}-\frac{1}{8}
= \frac{1}{16}
$,
$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{16}
= \frac{1}{16}
$,
and
$\frac{5}{16}-\frac{1}{4}
= \frac{1}{16}
$.

Since the difference between
consecutive terms is
$\frac{1}{16}$,
the next term should be
$\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{16}
=\frac{6}{16}
=\frac{3}{8}
$.